# Will the Mozambican authorities allow a tourist to cycle from Maputo to Pemba?

Tags: legal, event-based-effects, bicycles, mozambique

Given the [Renamo - government situation](https://www.google.com/search?q=mozambique%20rebel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=oX6kWKicGueo8wePk7vYCw#q=mozambique%20rebel&tbm=nws) will the Mozambican authorities allow a tourist (South African nationality) to cycle from southern Mozambique (Maputo) to the north (Pemba)?

Comment: IMHO unanswerable for now.